# How to call Edge Animate's play function from external Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, adobe-edge

I have a symbol on the stage called "cart".... inside the symbol is my graphic that has a motion path put on it to the timeline (it is called "car_v1").

On my stage I have a code to hide the symbol cart with an external CSS class :

```
sym.$("cart").addClass( "hidden" );  ( this is the css - .hidden { display: none; } )
```

I have a function that calls an external Javascript file.. from that external file I want to get the timeline animation to work:

Here is the function called:

```
checkCar();
```

and here is the function:

```
function checkCar() {
 if (AdobeEdge.countCar == 5){ 
 AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-172492634").getStage().$("cart").removeClass( "hidden" ); // this works!
 AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-172492634").getStage().$("cart").play(); //doesn't work!        <----this is the line I need help with!

// sym.getSymbol("cart").play(); // this works inside of edge and the timeline animation runs!!!

 }
}
```

Can anyone help me get the play function to work from my external Javascript file?

Answer (score 4):

ok, got it :)

AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-172492634").getStage().getSymbol("cart").play(); //works!

Comment: You ARE my champion! Thanks a million!!